# Make post-merge UI flow better when merging questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, merged-questions

After merging a question as a duplicate, StackExchange currently redirects to a page which gives a text summary of the operations carried out in the database...and that's it. No link back to the main site, no user-friendly messages - nothing. It looks like a hack job right now.

I think this can be prettified for a better workflow. At the very least, it should have a link back to the question it came from and/or the main site, and preferrably not just throw you to a page with a couple of lines of text but in the main site's layout.

Comment: If you're asking for improvements to the merge UI, I'd suggest going all the way and asking for improvements to the actual merging process, like being able to migrate answers/comments piecemeal, merging answers by the same user to both questions (for those rep whores that keep answering duplicates again and again and again), etc. Frankly, asking for a link back to the main site is pointless, since you can just click the header.

Comment: @LoremIpsum There's no header to click on. It literally takes you to a debug log type page with text. (I wish I'd taken a screenshot to illustrate this better.) I need to manually remove the extra bits in the URL in my address bar and return to the main site.

Answer (score -1):

Why exactly do we mods need a better UI for a feature that we use rarely? You have all the info you need on that page. Prettification generally involves reducing the amount if actual data shown -- not really necessary here.

Aside from putting the debuglog into the site wrapper for consistency's sake, I really don't think that anything else needs to be done :/